# Rails settings of devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, devise

I install devise gem in local machine. Everything is works. But then I transfered my app to Heroku I get that error, then create new user

```
Email translation missing: 
ru.activerecord.errors.models.user.attributes.email.taken
```

I suggest problem is there file config/environment/production.rb

```
config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { host: 'localhost', port: 3000 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happened because your language setting. 
Please check your config/locales/devise.ru.yml

```
ru: 
  activerecord:
    errors: 
      models  : 
        user: 
          attributes: 
            email: 
              taken: "Whatever you want"
```

If you feel that it happened because of sendgrid then please setup like below

```
config.action_mailer.asset_host = "YOUR-URL"
config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { :host => "YOUR-URL", :only_path => false }
config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
:address        => "smtp.sendgrid.net",
:port           => "25",
:authentication => :plain,
:user_name      => ENV['SENDGRID_USERNAME'],
:password       => ENV['SENDGRID_PASSWORD'],
:domain         => ENV['SENDGRID_DOMAIN']
```

}

Comment: You was right. Problem was with  config/locales/devise.ru.yml

Answer (score 0):

For heroku you have to set up `sendgrid` for mailers.

change your config for mailer in production with

```
config.log_formatter = ::Logger::Formatter.new
  config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { :host => 'your-domain' }
  ActionMailer::Base.smtp_settings = {
      :address        => "smtp.sendgrid.net",
      :port           => "25",
      :authentication => :plain,
      :user_name      => ENV['SENDGRID_USERNAME'],
      :password       => ENV['SENDGRID_PASSWORD'],
      :domain         => ENV['SENDGRID_DOMAIN']
  }
```

Comment: sendgrid is commercial. Is there non-commercial mailers?